# Concatenating Userform Data And Passing To Cell As Hyperlink

Tags: excel, hyperlink, userform, vba

I am trying to pass combined data from a user form to a cell to create a hyperlink.

I'm hoping to end up with a hyperlink structure as follows:

- Part 1: static folder location
- Part 2: First 2 characters from option selected in user form
- Part 3: Current Date and Time

I have all of this working in isolation:

1. `.Cells(lRow, 2).Value = "=Hyperlink(""H:\revised_action_tracker\test\"")"`
2. `.Cells(lRow, 3).Value = UCase(Left(Me.cbo_action_type.Value, 2))`
3. `.Cells(lRow, 4).Value = Format(CStr(Now), "yyyymmdd_hhmmss")`

When I attempt to join part 2 and 3 into the working Hyperlink from Part 1 it throws a Syntax error.

I'm expecting the hyperlink to look like this:

H:\revised_action_tracker\test\CT-20170322_162111

I feel like I'm going round in circles with this, any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: How are you attempting to join the three values? What would you like the outcome to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved if you process part 2 and 3 *before* step 1. This way you can add the texts from these two parts in the hyperlink formula:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 3).Value = UCase(Left(Me.cbo_action_type.Value, 2))
ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 4).Value = Format(CStr(Now), "yyyymmdd_hhmmss")
ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 2).Value = _
    "=Hyperlink(""H:\revised_action_tracker\test\" & _
    ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 3).Value & ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 4).Value & """)"
```

Or, if you don't wanna make it this large sentence, declare a variable to concatenate those strings, like this:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 3).Value = UCase(Left(Me.cbo_action_type.Value, 2))
ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 4).Value = Format(CStr(Now), "yyyymmdd_hhmmss")
Dim c As String: c = ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 3).Value & ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 4).Value
ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 2).Value = "=Hyperlink(""H:\revised_action_tracker\test\" & c & """)"
```

As an alternative, if you wanna setup a link without changing the text, you can create a cell with simple string and associate a hyperlink to it, instead of creating it with the formula HYPERLINK(). So you'd have something like this:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 2).Value = "H:\revised_action_tracker\test\"
ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 3).Value = UCase(Left(Me.cbo_action_type.Value, 2))
ActiveSheet.Cells(lRow, 4).Value = Format(CStr(Now), "yyyymmdd_hhmmss")
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(lRow, 2), Address:="H:\revised_action_tracker\test\" & Cells(lRow, 3) & Cells(lRow, 4)
```

Comment: I used your second solution, declaring the variable definitely helped when I needed to extend the hyperlink to include the value from another user input box.